DDD: Aggregate of aggregates
To practice in DDD, I'm trying to build a simple restaurant web site. I'm trying to understand when I should apply Aggregates and what are application limits if any.
Domain
The legend is following: we have a few places (restaurant chain?) with slightly different but intersecting menu. We want to have a website exposing that menu (with plans to add online ordering later).
I'm trying to model following set of entities:

Restaurant
Menu
Menu Category
Menu Item

To my mind each connection should be a composition (in UML terms):


Restaurant owns menus (one active, few drafts for the future, list of menu history). We don't want to manage them outside of restaurant. If restaurant gets deleted, all its menus should be removed as well. Only draft menus could be edited;
Menu owns set of categories, maintains their order, doesn't allow to change anything when it's read-only, has delete cascade;
Menu Category in its turn does the same for Menu Items.

In my vision, Menu Items are not reused across Menus. Menu Item is some kind of a snapshot that became immutable once Menu is activated.
Questions
In my readings on DDD I didn't see more then one level of aggregation. In those examples one aggregate could reference another one, but I didn't see nested aggregation.

Do I correctly understand when to use Aggregates in DDD? Or maybe I should just have separate entities?
Is that okay to have multi-level aggregates? Is that considered to be bad practice? Maybe it implies some difficulties in the future?

Will appreciate some good readings / videos / podcasts on the topic.
Thanks!
Update: Thoughts about @VoiceOfUnreason answer
Well, I see your points about the Restaurant entity, but the most complicated part for me is a Menu and its content.
If we think of an Aggregate as of Coarse-Grained Lock, that clearly doesn't make a lot of sense to have them nested. But if I look to it from the domain prospective, I see Menu as a solid thing, it is basically set of items, I can't freely change its items at any time, I can't really include same items into other menus, I need to maintain the order of items, etc.
So if I have Menu with Menu Items inside, that makes perfect sense and fits nicely into the DDD principles / approaches. But one thing: I need to group items within the menu into Categories. I should be able to maintain the order of Categories within a Menu and order of Menu Items within Category.
I can see an approach where I have Aggregate Root of Menu and it contains set of Categories and set of Menu Items, but does that simpler to model, understand and maintain? In this approach Menu entity will be overloaded with logic of managing Categories and Items.
Maybe I can consider Category as just a label of an Item (maybe ValueObject?) but again, who will manage the order of Items within Category?

Vaughn Vernon's series on aggregate design is worth reading: https://kalele.io/effective-aggregate-design/


An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.  (Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity at the Heart of Software, Chapter 6)

AGGREGATE is very similar to Coarse-Grained Lock (from Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture)

The aggregate's characteristics call for a Coarse-Grained Lock, since working with any of its members requires locking all of them.

So nesting aggregates gets a bit wonky: you've got some entity e within aggregate A within aggregate B.  When you want to change e, you "need" to lock A (because e is a member of A), and you "need" to lock B (because e is a member of B via composition), and if you always need to acquire lock A and also lock B together, is lock A actually doing anything useful?
The real motivation for aggregates is to make things easier for the humans to have to produce and maintain the model.  Nesting aggregates seems to fail that rule.
Expressed another way: nested aggregates suggests that you've got an impedance mismatch between your aggregate boundaries and the real needs of your problem domain, and you should probably fix that, rather than trying to get nesting to "work".
"Delete" tends to be a poor heuristic to use for understanding aggregates (see Udi Dahan 2009), in part because its a poor representation of what's going on in the business (closing a restaurant is a very different idea than destroying all records of a restaurant).
Instead, pay attention to how information changes, and which sorts of changes should be able to happen independently of one another.  For example, a restaurant's history of names, and a restaurant's history of owners, and a restaurant's history of menus -- is it really going to be to your advantage to combine these into a single aggregate, or would it instead be better to treat them a separate aggregates with their own locks?

Thank you for your answer! I see your points, I think I can already remove Restaurant entity from the equation, but I'm still struggling to understand the best approach for the Menu-Category-Item thing. I've updated the question with my thoughts, would love to hear opinion on that.
